# word-wrap not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html & css and I am trying something here but **word-wrap** property doesn't seem to be working here when I put line longer than width of element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b8Gn/1/) link with longer text line. (word-wrap property doesn't work here).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4DZG/) link with short text line.

```
/* Site Colors:
  #1A446C - blue grey
  #689DC1 - light blue
  #D4E6F4 - very light blue
  #EEE4B9 - light tan
  #8D0D19 - burgundy
*/

html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
body {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 13px; line-height: 15px;
  background: #EEE4B9;
}
img { border: none; }
a { color: #8D0D19; }
a:hover { color: #1A446C; }
    
#header { 
    height: 70px; 
    margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; 
  background: #1A446C; color: #D4E6F4;
}
#header h1 { padding: 1em; margin: 0; }
#main { 
    height: 600px; width: 100%; 
    margin: 0; padding: 0; 
    background: #EEE4B9;
}
#footer { 
    clear: both;
    height: 2em; margin: 0; padding: 1em; 
    text-align: center; 
  background: #1A446C;  color: #D4E6F4;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation { 
    float: left;
    width: 150px; height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; padding: 0 2em; 
    color: #D4E6F4; background: #8D0D19;
}
#navigation a { color: #D4E6F4; text-decoration: none; }
#navigation a:hover { color: #FFFFFF; }
ul.topics { 
    margin: 1em 0; padding-left: 0; list-style: none;
}

/* Page Content */
#page { 
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    word-wrap: normal;  
    padding-left: 2em; vertical-align: top; 
    background: #EEE4B9;
}
#page h2 { color: #8D0D19; margin-top: 1em;}
#page h3 { color: #8D0D19; }
```

I searched for it and I think it has something to do with float property but couldn't figure out what.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set a width on the #page element

```
#page {
    width: 600px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xupVJ/

Comment: This is not what i want. I want text to be adjacent to navigation not under it as in 2nd jsfiddle link mentioned in question.

Comment: That is why I gave two jsfiddle links :)